# Datatable Print Customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My datatable when printed has the date of printing on top. I want to change the format of that date to dd/mm/yy hh:mm. I have used javascript to initialize the title for datatable, but it appears in the header of the printed page as well as above the table. Also, in the footer of the printed page, I want to display my  website name. I couldn't find options to manipulate these. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

     var handleDataTableButtons = function() {
         if ($("#report").length) {
             $("#report").DataTable({

                 initComplete: function() {
                     this.api().columns().every(function() {
                         var column = this;
                         var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                             .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                             .on('change', function() {
                                 var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                     $(this).val()
                                 );

                                 column
                                     .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                     .draw();
                             });

                         column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                             select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                         });
                     });
                 },
                 dom: "Bfrtip",

                 buttons: [

                     {
                         extend: "excel",
                         className: "btn-sm"
                     },
                     /*    {
                           extend: "pdfHtml5",
                           className: "btn-sm"
                         },*/
                     {
                         extend: "print",
                         className: "btn-sm",
                         message: 'Message',
                         title: 'Some title',
                         customize: function(win) {
                             $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                 .addClass('compact')
                                 .css('font-size', '10pt');
                         }

                     },
                 ],
                 responsive: true
             });
         }
     };

     TableManageButtons = function() {
         "use strict";
         return {
             init: function() {
                 handleDataTableButtons();
             }
         };
     }();

     TableManageButtons.init();

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  id="report">
         <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Column1</th>
                   <th>Column2</th>       
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>Data1</td>
                  <td>Data2</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine I added the html and javascript code